# How to make sure your webapp is FISMA when hosting in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal

I want to host a webapp driven by Drupal in AWS. How to make sure my webapp is FISMA compliance? I know that AWS is FISMA compliance. Is that enough to make my app FISMA compliance?

Comment: The fact that the AWS platform is compliant with the requirements of the Federal Information Security Management Act (U.S.) has very little to do with whether your application itself is FISMA compliant.  While an application arguably can't possibly be compliant if hosted on an infrastructure that isn't compliant overall, the hosting platform is a tiny component of FISMA compliance, which requires certification and accreditation. If you have to ask, then you are likely a **long** way from compliant. Your question needs to be addressed to a qualified consultant. It isn't appropriate for web Q&A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, and covers specialized subject matter of a depth and breadth that seems to make it inappropriate for the Q&A format.